# Is a move operation in Unix atomic?

Tags: java, unix, file-locking

Suppose there are 2 processes P1 and P2, and they access a shared file `Foo.txt`.

Suppose P2 is reading from `Foo.txt`. I don't want P1 to write to `Foo.txt` while P2 is reading it.

So I thought I could make P1 write to `Foo.tmp` and as a last step, rename `Foo.tmp` to `Foo.txt`. My programming language is Java

So my question is, would this ensure that P2 reads the correct data from `Foo.txt`? Would the rename operation be committed once P2 completes reading the file?

**EDIT**

I tried to recreate this scenario as follows:

My P1 code is something like this:

```
File tempFile = new File(path1);
File realFile = new File(path2);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    writer.write("Hello World\n");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
tempFile.renameTo(realFile);
```

and my P2 code is :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
String line = null;
while(true) {
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
      System.out.println(line);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  br.close();
}
```

My Sample shared File:

```
Test Input
Test Input
Test Input
```

I'm starting P1 and P2 almost simulataneously (P2 starting first).

So according to my understanding, even though P1 has written a new Foo.txt, since P2 is already reading it, it should read the old Foo.txt content until it re-opens a BufferedReader to Foo.txt.

But what actually happens is P2 reads `Test Input` thrice, as is expected from the input, but after that it reads the new content which was written by P1.

Output from P2:

```
Test Input
Test Input
Test Input 
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
 .
 .
 .
```

So it doesn't work as it should. Am I testing this scenario wrong? I feel like there's something I'm missing out.

Comment: Have you considered using a database for something like this? You'd get a history, and your second process can just `select text from foo where insertstamp = max(insertstamp)`

Comment: @corsiKa, using a database isn't possible. The shared file in question interacts with a lot of modules which would have to be changed.

Comment: This is indeed a common idiom in Unix (atomic-rename). Though in C, there is usually a `fsync()` before the `rename()`, to provide ordering guarantees even when there are OS/hardware crashes.

Comment: your P2 code looks like you're closing the file each time in the loop, so the next iteration will have to reopen the file (which will get the new file if it has since been changed).  With no explicit reopen, I would expect it to fail, but I don't know java, so I guess it is implicitly reopening the file?

Comment: I don't think it is re-opening the file at every iteration. The reason I say this is because I'm running P1 after 1 iteration of P2 (when it prints `Test Input` once. So if it's reopening the file at every iteration, at the 2nd iteration, it should print the new data. But it prints `Test Input` thrice, which means it isn't closing the file

Answer (score 43):

A UNIX `rename` operation is atomic (see rename(2)).  The UNIX `mv` command uses rename if the source and target path are on the same physical device.  If the target path is on a different device, the rename will fail, and `mv` will copy the file (which is not atomic).

If the target file path exists, the `rename` will atomically remove it from the file system and replace it with the new file.  The file won't actually be deleted until its reference count drops to zero, so if another process is currently reading the file, it will keep reading the old file.  Once all processes have closed the old file, its reference count will drop to zero and the file storage space will be reclaimed.

Comment: Are disks in RAID setup also seen as the same physical device?

Comment: This is a great answer. FWIW, here are 2 relevant pages for mv and rename that outline why this is true. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1p.html

Answer (score 6):

why not use `FileChannel.lock` ?

here is an example:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/filelock/create-shared-file-lock-on-file/

Comment: Yes, I ended up using this after I posted my question, but I'm still curious about how this would work

Answer (score 4):

1. move(rename) is atomic if done on the same device. (device = same disk/partition)
2. If `Foo.txt` exits move `Foo.tmp` to `Foo.txt` most likely will fail. (But if you first delete `Foo.txt` and then move, it should work). What happens is that a file is not physically deleted until all file handlers are closed (there is no process that uses that file). Also, after remaining `Foo.tmp` to `Foo.txt` you will have 2 Foo.txt files. One that is deleted but still opened in memory (basically that file does not have a reference on disk anymore) and one that actually resides on disk.
3. But, after move, in second process you need to reopen the file.

Let me know if we are on the same page with #1.

Comment: what do you mean by "device", could you elaborate please?

Comment: Yes, we are on the same page with #1

Comment: @Chaos I changed the explanation for #2 also to make it clear what actually happens.

Comment: Moving on top of existing file works too. Otherwise it would not be possible to eg. securely replace file under `/tmp/` in a multiuser system.