# Is console.log atomic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, parallel-processing

The `print` statement in Python is not thread-safe. Is it safe to use `console.log` in Node.js concurrently?

If so, then is it also interleave-safe? That is, if multiple (even hundreds) of callbacks write to the console, can I be sure that the output won't be clobbered or interleaved?

Looking at the source code, it seems that Node.js queues concurrent attempts to write to a stream ([here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L266)). On the other hand, `console.log`'s [substitution flags come from `printf(3)`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data). If `console.log` wraps around `printf`, then that can interleave output on POSIX machines ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467949/850206)).

Please show me where the [`async ._write(chunk, encoding, cb)` is implemented](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L2) inside Node.js in your response to this question.

EDIT: If it is fine to write to a stream concurrently, then why does [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-write-stream-atomic) exist?

Comment: Node.js is single threaded. Callbacks may originate from different threads, but once they enter the main thread, nothing is concurrent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything in node.js is basically "atomic". That's because node.js is single threaded - no code can ever be interrupted.

Comment: Note though; there are issues with `console.log` object evaluation being lazy in browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays. Shouldn't impact node.js apps, though.

Comment: Can someone please explain how can Node be single-threaded and still from callback hell? I mean.. What you're saying is that, even though there may be 2000 callbacks going on, just one of them will be executed at a time until it's finished or blocked by a non-CPU bound operation?

Comment: @andrerpena: Yes, only one of them will be executed at any time, but all 2000 can be WAITING in parallel. That's what concurrency means - code can WAIT in parallel without executing. Concurrency != parallelism.

Comment: OK, but 'atomic' writes by character? By a newline? Also please see the edits I made since you answered this question. I understand in theory what you mean, but I need a deeper explanation.

Comment: @andrerpena: Here are two previous answers I've written explaining the architecture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616477/does-javascript-process-using-an-elastic-racetrack-algorithm/19620041#19620041, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883525/i-know-that-callback-function-runs-asynchronously-but-why/29885509#29885509

Comment: @Coder: No, atomic means the execution of the `console.log()` function itself, including the internal call to `printf()` etc. No function in js actually write directly to stdout. Instead it queues the writing in the event loop (the code you found). So `atomic` writes by "message".

Comment: @Coder: Note that node.js uses one thread for everything: console, sockets etc. The only exception is disk I/O, then node uses one thread per file which still means that I/O is technically thread safe.

Comment: @slebetman: I can accept your answer if you amend it to include where the NPM package comes from and where the async _write function is implemented in the source code.

Comment: The NPM package is to handle the case where TWO programs write to the same file. His solution is to write to a temp file and THEN copy it to place (on unix rename is atomic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706419/is-a-move-operation-in-unix-atomic). This is to handle the case where the node process has race condition with another node process or a C program or a Ruby process or a Perl process etc.

Answer (score 1):

The events loop of nodejs is single thread, but all the async calls of nodejs are multi-threaded, it use libuv under the hood, libuv is library that use multi threads.

link:
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see on my Node.js console it is NOT "interleave-safe".

I can see my console-output is sometimes "clobbered or interleaved". Not always. When I run my program it is maybe every 5th time that I see interleaved output from multiple log-statements.

This may of course depend on your Node.js version and the OS you are running it on. For the record my Node.js version is v12.13.0 and OS is Windows 10.0.19042.